# Delete all SQLite rows NOT IN specific rows

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database for my leaderboard. Currently, I insert all scores into my leaderboard, and select the 5 highest scores to show on my app. I think it would take up too much room to never delete the other scores, so I would like to delete them. How can I do this?

Here's how I select the top 5 scores, ranked first by score and second by time if score is equal:

```
    public  Cursor gethmLeaderboard(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String[] columns = {TableInfo.LB_RANK, TableInfo.LB_SCORE, TableInfo.LB_TIME};

    Cursor c = db.query(TableInfo.TABLE_HM, null, null, null, null, null, TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " + TableInfo.LB_TIME + " ASC", "5");
    return c;

}
```

Here's how I create my table:

```
public String CREATE_HMQUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableInfo.TABLE_HM + "("
        + TableInfo.LB_RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 1 ," + TableInfo.LB_SCORE +
        " INT,"+ TableInfo.LB_TIME + " VARCHAR );";
```

I want to delete all rows NOT IN that query. How can I do that?

**What I've tried:**

```
public String DEL_ALLBUTES = "DELETE FROM " +
        TableInfo.TABLE_HM + " WHERE " +
        TableInfo.LB_RANK + " NOT IN (SELECT " +
        TableInfo.LB_RANK + " FROM " +
        TableInfo.TABLE_HM + " ORDER BY " +
        TableInfo.LB_SCORE + " DESC, " +
        TableInfo.LB_TIME + " ASC LIMIT 5);";
```

In this format:

```
db.rawQuery(DEL_ALLBUTES, null);
```

But when I check the database there are still tons of rows so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` for **commands** (everything which is not a SELECT).
And `rawQuery()` for **queries** (SELECT).

Comment: OK! I got a different result. Now I get a runtime error at my execSQL() statement

Comment: It seems like db is null... but I can't tell, since I see no context near that command.

Comment: I took out null from the exec statement and no it is db.execSQL(DEL_ROWHM5); and it works.